# Link a subdomain to a web service hosted in IIS in windows Server

Tags: redirect, iis, dns, windows-server

I have a WCF web service on windows server hosted in port 80 on IIS. I have a sub domain too. I want link subdomain to my web service.

For example:
My server IP: 91.106.223.89
My domain : sub.mydomain.com

now when I search address "http://91.106.223.89" in browser, I see my web service.
I want when search "sub.mydomain.com" , I see my web service.

I did some config on DNS Server but is not OK.

Comment: "I did some config on DNS Server", so what did you do? Besides, what are the site bindings? https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: Can you post the configuration information of your site?